# Change one disc to AHCI

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, windows-10, bios, raid

I have one SSD that I'd like to use in AHCI mode, and two discs in RAID mode. Right now all discs are in RAID - the SSD, and two HDDs. I would like to change only one of them to AHCI?

I found in the UEFI settings an option to change the mode, but it's for all discs. I'd rather not like to test it because it's raid-0, and I don't want to lose any data.

How can I change only of my disks to AHCI?

Comment: Even if you did switch it you wouldn't lose data until you actually made a change to the data on the disks.  Of course you should not change it because your current configuration is already correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The AHCI vs. RAID mode is for the entire HDD controller, not the individual drives.  To have one drive AHCI and still keep the RAID, you'd need a separate HDD controller for the other drive.

In the way the controllers handle them, AHCI is simply/basically a one-drive RAID, so leave it as RAID and just don't join the single disk to an array.

If for some reason required by the controller you can only access the drives in the OS if they are in an array, put it in a RAID0 array by itself (or use JBOD, if offered; exact methods depend on the specific RAID controller).

Comment: I will translate what Techie007 just said.  Your current configuration is **correct** and it should not be changed.

Comment: Yeah, I understood perfectly well what he said, thanks.